# unquoted newline found in data error and date/time field value out of range error while copying into pgadmin

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE procedurehistory (
    petid varchar,
    proceduredate date,
    proceduretype varchar,
    proceduresubcode varchar
);
```

```
COPY procedurehistory FROM 'C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Databases\ProceduresHistory.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

the given .csv file link is https://sds-platform-private.s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/P9-ProceduresHistory.csv

Error faced

```
ERROR:  unquoted newline found in data
HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent a newline.
CONTEXT:  COPY procedurehistory, line 103
SQL state: 22P04
```

Then I tried adding a page break in the excel file where the data ended
Now, facing a new error

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "13-01-16"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
CONTEXT:  COPY procedurehistory, line 13, column proceduredate: "13-01-16"
SQL state: 22008
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the CSV file in `vim`, you'll see that some lines don't end with a newline (`^M`).  Since the CSV header of your particular file expects a newline, the rest of the CSV should have a newline at the end of each entry.  One solution is to add a `^M` by typing `Ctrl-V` + `Ctrl-M` for each line that doesn't have a newline, or just remove all newlines completely from the CSV:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.6.17)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# COPY procedurehistory FROM '/tmp/foo.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
ERROR:  unquoted newline found in data
HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent newline.
CONTEXT:  COPY procedurehistory, line 103: ""
postgres=# \q
-bash-4.2$ sed -i "s/^M//g" /tmp/P9-ProceduresHistory.csv > /tmp/foo.csv
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.6.17)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# COPY procedurehistory FROM '/tmp/foo.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
COPY 2284
```